# Want to eliminate: "[WARNING] Could not determine source for class com.mycompany.MyClass_" when building Java + Scala project

Tags: java, scala, maven, scoverage, scala-maven-plugin

I am using maven with the scala-maven-plugin for building a project that is a mixture of Java 1.8 and Scala 2.12.7 code.  When I build from the command line with:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

I get messages like:

> "[WARNING] Could not determine source for class
> com.mycompany.MyClass_".

`com.mycompany.MyClass` is an annotated Java class that exists in my project.  Note that the warning message has an underscore after "MyClass".  There is no Java source code for a class named `com.mycompany.MyClass_` in my project, but there is a class file at `target/classes/com/mycompany/MyClass_.class`.

What can I do to determine the cause of these warnings and remove them?  (I can get rid of them by commenting out the `scala-maven-plugin` section of my pom file, but that seems a little extreme.)

**Additional diagnostic data**:

Following @Joachim Sauer's advice, I used `javap` to look at the class file.  The output included:

> Compiled from "MyClass_.java"

I did a search for "MyClass_.java" from the root of the project.  It was found in

```
target/scoverage-classes/com/mycompany/MyClass_.java
```

When I look at that class in the editor, it includes:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(FileMetadata.class)
```

So it looks like the file generated by SCoverage and/or `JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor` is not locatable by some other tool.  I'll dig some more...

Comment: Where does these warnings appear? IDE? When running a command?

Comment: Can you create a minimal example showing the error you can share?

Comment: Do you have both classes `com.mycompany.MyClass` and `com.mycompany.MyClass_`? Do both of them have sources? Please show your `pom.xml`. If you're not sure about the classes please run `Class.forName("com.mycompany.MyClass").getResource("MyClass.class")`, `Class.forName("com.mycompany.MyClass_").getResource("MyClass_.class")` to see where these classes come from. Does your project use any code generation so that `MyClass_` can be auto generated?

Comment: Does your project use Java annotation processing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558849/how-do-i-build-a-mixed-java-scala-project-which-uses-java-annotation-code-genera

Comment: @kc2001 I can see that you found that question too.

Comment: @DmytroMitin - I added answers to your questions to the problem description.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - I'm trying to create a minimal example, but it's slow going.  There are many inter-class dependencies, and it's difficult to know which part of the project to concentrate on.

Comment: @GaëlJ - I added my mvn command to the problem description.

Comment: *Something* seems to be generating this class and *something* (probably something other than the first something) is complaining about there being no source (which is weird, because few tools need access to the class *and* the source file). Your focus for the [mre] should be to identify the two somethings: Figure out which thing generates the weirdly-named class (maybe by inspecting it via `javap` to see what it contains) and what complains about it afterwards.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - I followed your advice.  Something-1 seems to be SCoverage.  I'm still working on determining Something-2.  I updated the question with the current findings.

Comment: @kc2001 Could you try to add additional source directory `target/scoverage-classes` (similarly to `Compile / unmanagedSourceDirectories += ...` in sbt)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752972/how-to-add-an-extra-source-directory-for-maven-to-compile-and-include-in-the-bui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270445/maven-compile-with-multiple-src-directories